# Split with this char : "\"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a problem with the .split() function ,  I have the following string:

```
var imageUrl = "Images\Products\randomImage.jpg";
```

And I want to split by the character "\", but, this happens:

```
 //If dont use double "\\", throws me an error.
 var imageUrlArray = imageUrl.split("\\");
```

Then the variable has this value:

```
"ImagesProductsrandoImage.jpg"
```

I need to do that, because need to change this "\" into "/", because makes me an error with a plugin. The original String is obtained from the DataBase.

Comment: Whats the desired output? You want to split based on the character into an array? Or you want to replace '\' with nothing?

Comment: Why not doing it before writing it into the variable `imageUrl`? Do it server-side or something like that.

Comment: I don't give the value to the variable,is given from from a query from the database, I don't have the control of the db.
How I said in the question, I need to change the "\" char, into "/".

Answer (score 4):

The first `\` is escaping the second `\` character. Your string should also be doubled up.

```js
var imageUrl = "Images\\Products\\randomImage.jpg";
var updated = imageUrl.replace(/\\/g,"/");
console.log(updated);
```

Comment: OP says they are getting the string from the database though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the file string so that the backslashes there become "\", then you can preform your split, and then un-escape the resulting array of strings for other characters that may have been backslashed.

Not too familiar with Javascript but it probably looks something like this:

$fileName = `escape($fileName)`